# Supplementary information gives problems with numbering of subsection

Tags: sectioning, appendix, section-titles

I used to make the Appendix by calling it "Appendix" in the following way:

```
% in the following I just show the documentclass in case it is relevant

\documentclass[aps,pre,onecolumn,noshowpacs,superscriptaddress,groupedaddress,preprintnumbers,nofootinbib,showpacs,12pt]{revtex4}

% here I start the appendix

\appendix
\section{title of the first section of the appendix}
```

but now I will need to call it "Supplementary Information" rather than "Appendix". 
If I just add a section

```
\section{Supplementary Information}
```

of course it will be numbered in the same way as the other sections. I do not want it. So I try

```
\section*{Supplementary Information}
\subsection{first section of SI}
```

But then the style of the title changes and in addition the SI subsections follow the numbering of the subsections of previous sections, rather than starting from `1` (or `A`). 
Finally, if I do

```
\section*{Supplementary Information}
\subsection*{first section of SI}
```

the SI sections have no number at all. That's not what I want. I want the SI sections to be numbered starting from the first SI section, and I want the SI title to have no number (and possibly be all capital letters).

How can I do it?

Comment: can you please post a screenshot or hand drawn sketch of what is your end requirement--rest of the things the latex experts will manage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your preamble put:

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Supplementary Information}
```